# Python pie chart / Show several columns combined

Tags: pandas, pie-chart

I have dataframe with 2 columns:

Col1- managers' name

Col2 - their profit

I want plot a pie chart where I can show most profitable 5 managers seperately , and others in one slice as 'others'

Comment: What did you try so far ? Are you using pandas ?

Comment: I use pandas and matplotlib and didnt try anything.

Comment: How about my answer, does it work for you ?

Comment: I  selected another way . Thank you . It would be highly appreciated if you tell me how I can show data on/under bar chart in pandas.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could show your approach or mark my answer as accepted, since it works for the question asked. Do you mean data in form of a table together with the plot ?

Comment: I did. 
Yes , or numbers on each bar

Comment: This might work for you https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html

Comment: I changed my answer to demonstrate how to use the autopct argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that:
With automatic labeling of the pie pieces using autopct argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data  = {'managers':['mike1','mike2','mike3','mike4','mike5','mike6','mike7'],
'profit':[110,60,40,30,10,5,5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.sort_values(by = 'profit', ascending = False)

top_5 = df.iloc[:5] 

others = df.iloc[5:]['profit'].sum()

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['others',others]], columns = ['managers','profit'])

all_data = top_5.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

all_data.index = all_data['managers']

#func to lable the pieces
def auto_func(val):
    return(round(val)) 

all_data.plot.pie(y = 'profit', autopct = auto_func)

# ax = plt.gca()

plt.show()
```